# Setting up environment for SQL queries

Tags: postgresql

I know the basic syntax of queries but otherwise I'm a beginner with SQL.

I have an SQL file (.sql) and I downloaded a couple programs (pgadmin and sql workbench).

I have no idea how to get from where I am now to actually writing queries and finding information. How do I set up so I can actually import my SQL file and start writing queries?

Comment: Download [Oracle Database 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) and install it following some youtube video (Many are available). Then you can run sql file using `sqlplus` of Oracle Database

Comment: You will need to install PostgreSQL if you haven't already.  Or you can use another database server, I am assuming PostgreSQL because you mention pgadmin in your question.

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Oracle is rarely the answer for a beginner to SQL ;)

Do you know where the SQL file came from? Did you write it yourself or download it from a website?

Note that despite the fact it is all SQL, Oracle SQL is different to MySQL SQL which is different again to MSSQL SQL and again to PostgreSQL - if you don't know what created the file, you need to find that out first.

Comment: I was able to figure it out with this document: http://get.enterprisedb.com/docs/Tutorial_All_PP_pgAdmin_Backup_Restore.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) is the default GUI for [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).
[SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) is a free, DBMS-independent, cross-platform SQL query tool.

Either way, you need to connect to a database to actually run queries. The DBMS can either run on your local machine or you can connect to a remote server - where you need access privileges of course.